# Getting JSON Array And JSON object in same key

Tags: android, json, gson

i am getting response in Json array and json object in same key.Json Array is working fine but while   parsing json Object  i am getting an error

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was 
  BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 204 path $.RenewalPlans.RenewalPlan
```

Json Object

```
 {"Code":"000","Message":"Success","UserName":"abc","CustomerName":"abc And 
 Company","PaymentMessage":"You have 55 days left, you can make ADVANCE 
 payment","RenewalPlans":{"RenewalPlan":{"PlanId":"11111","PlanName":"plan 
 name","PlanAmount":"1000"}}}
```

Json Array

```
{"Code":"000","CustomerName":"abc","Message":"Success","PaymentMessage":"You have 2 days left, you can make ADVANCE payment","RenewalPlans":{"RenewalPlan":[{"PlanAmount":"100","PlanId":"1","PlanName":"Value Standard 25mbps/12mths 1TV (Renew) "},{"PlanAmount":"200","PlanId":"2","PlanName":"30Mbps/12mths SPECIAL OFFER 2077 (1TV) "},{"PlanAmount":"300","PlanId":"3","PlanName":"40Mbps/12mths SPECIAL OFFER 2077 (2TV) (Rs.19775)"},{"PlanAmount":"400","PlanId":"4","PlanName":"60Mbps/12mths SPECIAL OFFER 2077 (3TV) "}]},"Username":"abcd"}
```

`

```
 String data;
 Object json = null;
                    
CustomerdetailsResponse customerDetailsResponse = new Gson().fromJson(new Gson().toJson(response), CustomerdetailsResponse.class);
data = new Gson().toJson(customerDetailsResponse.getRenewalPlans().getRenewalPlan());

                    try {
                        json = new JSONTokener(data).nextValue();
                        if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
                            CustomerDetailsResponseRenewalPlansRenewalPlan plans = new Gson().fromJson(new Gson().toJson(data), CustomerDetailsResponseRenewalPlansRenewalPlan.class);
                            renewalPlans.add(plans);
                        }
                        //you have an object
                        else if (json instanceof JSONArray) {

                            renewalPlans = new Gson().fromJson(data, new TypeToken<ArrayList<RenewalPlans>>() {
                            }.getType());
                     
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

factory register with Gson

```
 public Gson gson()
{
    return Converters.registerAll(new GsonBuilder())
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(AppTypeAdapterFactory.create())

            .setLenient()
            .create();
}
```

GsonType Adapter factory

```
@GsonTypeAdapterFactory
public abstract class AppTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    public  static TypeAdapterFactory create(){
        return new AutoValueGson_AppTypeAdapterFactory();
    }

}
```

Comment: appears that your second json response is not correct, please cross check. Welcome to stack overflow!!

Comment: I did check my response however im getting error while parsing json object @AbhishekChoudhary